# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Gone'

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Bot Info:

- Bot Framework SDK Version: 4.3.2
- SDK Platform: .NET Core 3.1
- Active Channels: Microsoft Teams Chatbot
- Deployment Environment: Azure App Service (West Europe)

I am facing the issue after migrated LUIS; it changed appkey, appID and hostname. I have configured it (correctly) and have saved it. I have restarted the machine, however when I checked local emulator it was not working. Then I redeployed it to azure servers, which still showing some error message about the chatbot " Operation returned an invalid status code 'Gone'".

```
// Create the LUIS settings from configuration.
//Get all the LUIS related details from Env variables.

var luisApplication = new LuisApplication(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LuisAppId"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LuisAPIKey"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LuisAPIHostName")
  );

var recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication);
```

The actual call to LUIS will return the identified intent and entities

`recognizerResult = awaitrecognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext,cancellationToken);`

However the response back says "The application d1e6b8a0-47bb-4890-9250-6fb3f2d2bb62 is not published in slot Production"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the response is quit clear:

> "The application d1e6b8a0-47bb-4890-9250-6fb3f2d2bb62 is not published
> in slot Production"

Go to luis portal and publish your app in Production slot

[image]